# гит в состоянии - rebasing repo

Tags: git, github

добрый день. поторопился и отправил коммит в удаленный репозиторий, а в репозитории были изменения которые я не взял себе. Теперь попал в такую ситуацию, как можно вернуть все назад:

У к истории добавилась ещё одна ветка, с которой не могу переключится и дальше вести разработку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что говорит при переключении?

Comment: `git rebase --abort`?

Comment: если локально ничего важного не осталось, можно удалить ветку master и создать заново после чекаута на origin/master